# Maximo Anywhere Eclipse does not show Platform folder and js files of platform folder fater configuring

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have to modify a class which is Platform folder in Maximo Anywhere where but eclipse does not show this folder and related classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting in eclipse. Right click on the application and select properties. Then Resource, and Resource Filters. Remove the exclusion and it will be visible.  [image]